# Setting Different Permissions to users view terms in TermStore

Tags: permissions, taxonomy, term, app-permissions

I need to set different permissions to users view terms.

For example, supposing that a have a TermStoreCollection named Regions, and 3 users…

User
-> Sarah
-> Mike
-> John

Regions
-> North
-> South
-> East
-> West
-> Northeast
-> Southeast 
-> Southwest
-> Northwest

…I need to set permission to Sarah list only terms ‘North, East and west’. Set ‘South’ term for John, and ‘Northwest’ to Mike. So in this case, John only sees ‘South’ term, and nobody lists others terms.

Can I set user permission to a single term?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wont work

the MMS does not support permissions.